# html5 video interactive objects

Tags: html, video

Does anyone know if html5 video allows objects like buttons, menu, etc connected to the timeline?

Youtube flash player do this: in specific moment, show an object (banner, links, comments) over the video for defined seconds.

thanks

Comment: The HTML5 Video tag plays the video, but it also has a lot of features that allow you to add a layer of interactivity on top of the video. Popcorn.js does this, and H5P also has an interactive video library where you may add extra textual information, images and quizzes to the video timeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no,
It's possible to create very interactive video-based presentations using html5 video objects however it requires a lot more than just the video object itself. You can nest video into a canvas object then mess with the actual video image frames, you can overlay any visual html element on top of the video object itself then animate these, you can control the video playback with buttons, click events etc. You can even have the video object control the rest of the page with time-based listeners.

Popcorn.js is really really good and easy to learn, allowing you to do all of what you mentioned.
http://popcornjs.org

http://popcornjs.org/demos

Comment: i guess videos inside canvas is the most complete solutions.

Comment: yes it's a more controlled environment than the dom is also it's generally less resource heavy as dom elements are rendered slightly differently by the browser and are subject to a lot of global listeners & events. it would be more accessible to do it via the dom though.

Answer (score 4):

It's not part of the HTML5 video standard, but it's easy to implement manually by wiring up some scripting to the `progress` event. By looking at the `currentTime` property of the video object you can decide when to show/hide additional elements.

eg showing an element on top of a video between 1 and 2 seconds into a video:

```
<video id="v">...</div>
<div id="overlay" style="position: relative; top: -80px;">HELLO</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var overlay= document.getElementById('overlay');
    var video= document.getElementById('v');
    video.addEventListener('progress', function() {
        var show= video.currentTime>=1 && video.currentTime<2;
        overlay.style.visibility= show? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: In addition, if it was simply static text WebVTT (and one of the many polyfills out there) could be used.

Answer (score 1):

X2TV ([www.x2.tv](http://www.x2.tv)) has a drag and drop studio where you can overlay icons and additional content within the HTML5 layer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you woul like to use a more generic framework https://github.com/nise/vi-two could be interesting for you.